# Jquery exporting table to csv hidden table cells

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, html-table

I need to be able to export a HTML table to CSV. I found a snippet somewhere; it works but not entirely how I want it to.

In my table (in the fiddle) I have hidden fields, I just use quick n dirty inline styling and inline onclicks to swap between what you see.

What I want with the export is that it selects the table as currently displayed. so only the td's where `style="display:table-cell"`. I know how to do this in normal JS.

```
    document.querySelectorAll('td[style="display:table-cell"])');
```

but how can I do this using the code I have right now in the exportTableToCSV function?

(sorry but the text in the fiddle is in dutch as its a direct copy of the live version).
The fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5hfcjkdh/

Answer (score 0):

In your grabRow method you can filter out the hidden table cells using [jQuery's :visible selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).  Below is an example

```
function grabRow(i, row) {

    var $row = $(row);
    //for some reason $cols = $row.find('td') || $row.find('th') won't work...
    //Added :visisble to ignore hidden ones
    var $cols = $row.find('td:visible'); 
    if (!$cols.length) $cols = $row.find('th:visible');

    return $cols.map(grabCol)
                            .get().join(tmpColDelim);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i solved it. Decided to step away from a pure javascript solution to take processing stress off the client and instead handle it server side.

Because i already get the data from the database using a stored procedure i use this to just get the dataset again and convert it into an ViewExportModel so i have a TotalViewExport and a few trimmed variations (reuse most of them) based on a Selected variable i fill a different model.

Added to the excisting show function to update a Selected variable to keep track of the currently selected view.

When the user clicks Export table to excel it calls to the controller of the current page, IE. AlarmReport (so AlarmReportController) and i created the action ExportReports(int? SelectedView);

In addition i added [CsvExport](https://github.com/jitbit/CsvExport/blob/master/CsvExport.cs) as a manager. This takes data results (so c# models/ iqueryables/ lists/ etc). and puts them into a Csv set. using the return type BinaryContent one can export a .csv file with this data.

The action ExportReports calls the stored procedure with the selectedview parameter. The result gets pumped into the correct model. this model is pumped into the CsvExport model as rows.

The filename is made based on the selected view + What object is selected + current date(yyyy-MM-dd). so for example "Total_Dolfinarium_2016-05-13". lets

lastly the action returns the .csv file as download using the BinaryContent Returntype and ExportToBytes from the CsvExport

The export part of this action is programmed like so(shortened to leave some checks out like multiple objects selected etc)(data and objectnames are gathred beforehand):

```
public ActionResult ExportCsv(CsvExport Data, string ObjectName, string Type){
   var FileName = Type + "_" + ObjectName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    return BinaryContent("text/csv", FileName + ".csv", Data.ExportToBytes());

}
```